# Segmentation fault в .Net приложении

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, отладка, gdb

Имеется [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) приложение, которое использует в том числе вызовы из нативных [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) библиотек. В поисках проблем в этих библиотеках, приложение было запущено под отладчиков [gdb](/questions/tagged/gdb) в Windows. Однако, отладчик выявил проблему сегментирования в потоке, который, судя по всему, относится к управляемому коду.

> ```
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> [Switching to Thread 287244.0x59c74]
> 0x70f34bb6 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d54
> 28f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> ```

Не очень понятно, что бы это могло значить и какие дальнейшие шаги стоит предпринять для поиска источника ошибки.

Back trace отладчика прилагаю:

> ```
> (gdb) bt
> #0  0x70f34bb6 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d54
> 28f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> #1  0x0b6e3356 in ?? ()
> #2  0x70a5ebf5 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d54
> 28f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> #3  0x70a6e04c in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d54
> 28f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> #4  0x7161b386 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\affcb83bba04f782
> c2586a1788330891\mscorlib.ni.dll
> #5  0x7161b341 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\affcb83bba04f782
> c2586a1788330891\mscorlib.ni.dll
> #6  0x70a6c81f in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d54
> 28f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> #7  0x70a5eb7e in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d54
> 28f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> #8  0x70ebbed2 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d5-
> 428f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> #9  0x70a5ebf5 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d54
> 28f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> #10 0x70a6c82e in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d54
> 28f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> #11 0x70a5eb7e in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d54
> 28f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> #12 0x70ea49ac in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d03eb8a47500f40d54
> 28f9c6875f8e56\System.ni.dll
> #13 0x716bfccf in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\affcb83bba04f782
> c2586a1788330891\mscorlib.ni.dll
> #14 0x716bfb9a in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\affcb83bba04f782
> c2586a1788330891\mscorlib.ni.dll
> #15 0x725e366f in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> #16 0x725ed376 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> #17 0x726bc6bc in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> #18 0x725ed6b7 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> #19 0x725ed721 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> #20 0x725ed7ee in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> #21 0x725ed868 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> #22 0x726bc650 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> #23 0x726bb4cf in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> #24 0x726e60d1 in ?? ()
>    from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> #25 0x7675338a in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk ()
>    from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
> #26 0x77289902 in ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain ()
>    from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
> #27 0x772898d5 in ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain ()
>    from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
> #28 0x00000000 in ?? ()
> ```

Отладка усугубляется ещё тем, что проблема проявляется относительно редко (~1 раз за 10 часов работы). Всё это время программа работает в одном и том же режиме, т.е. нет (неизвестно) какого-то определенного действия, которое позволило бы отложить или приблизить момент проявления ошибки при работе в заданном режиме.

Есть ли у кого какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Похоже на испорченную память. Есть возможность запустить под контролирующей программой наподобие valgrind?

Comment: @VladD возможность запустить есть, но не оч.ясно что должно быть под Windows на подобии valgrind в данном случае.

Comment: Возможно, [AppVerifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: А вообще, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows